# replacing the character with another one on deleting

Tags: javascript, jquery

For ex: I have input with this value: (099) 123 45 67
I want to replace the digits with underline (`_`) on deleting as this: (099) 123 __ __

How I do? I have the function which returns me the current character position. Then with `charAt()` I get the character and then replace it using `replace()`. But if there is more than one the same characters it replaces the first one, not the one which next to cursor.
Have any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "on deleting"?

Comment: on pressing "Backspace" and "Delete"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the standard `replace()` function could accomodate this type of replace.

You'd have to use `substring()` to split the string into to (one string before the character and one after) and then concatonate them back together with the `'_'` in between.

Answer (score 0):

Use replace as Regex function. Do this by having search expression in slashes. To find all occurrences (all numbers, instead of only first), use it with global option by adding a 'g' after search expression.
In your case, you should use replace(/[0-9]/g, "_")

Comment: The OP doesn't want to replace all instances, they want to replace a single instance, but at a particular place in the string.

Comment: Then how about str[particularPlace] = "_" ?

Comment: Would be nice if it worked, but doesn't appear to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Different answer - somewhat resembling what @samjudson said:

You need to use substring, but it's a bit complicated.

For IE or Opera use this object: `document.selection.createRange().text = "_";`

For Mozilla browsers use:

```
inputBox.focus();
var position = inputBox.selectionStart; //selectionEnd would work as well
inputBox.value = inputBox.value.substring(0, position) + '_' +
inputBox.value.substring(position, inputBox.value.length);
```

Idea from RT editors, such as this one :), and the one on Wikipedia.

Comment: Really it's very complicated. I know the link where it works ideally. Maybe it can help on finding the solution http://tinkoff.ru (click on the 4th input field)

Comment: It's different - they add the underscore at the end, not where you deleted.

Comment: what is the best way to do so?